# removing '<' '>' chars from string using regexp in matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

In my simulink i have a propagate signal which look like this:

```
<foo_boo>
```

and at source

```
foo_boo
```

i would like to build a regular expression the return from

```
<foo_boo>
```

simply *foo_boo* and from foo_boo i would like to get *foo_boo*.

In other words, i would like a regular expression that remove '>' and '<' from my string and the string can include [a-zA-Z_0-9] chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty easy.  Use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to search for symbols that contain `<` or `>` in your input string and replace them with nothing.  In other words:

```
out = regexprep(in, '<|>', '');
```

`in` would be the string you want to operate on (i.e. `<foo_boo>`) and `out` contains the processed string.

Example:

```
in = '<foo_boo>';
out = regexprep(in, '<|>', '')

out =

foo_boo
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I think logical indexing is the answer to most things MATLAB (the other being `bsxfun`), I throw this in:

```
str = '<foo_boo>';
str( (str=='<') | (str=='>') ) = [];
```

Comment: I've read a few of your answers.  You do certainly favour logical indexing.  +1.

Comment: Also forgot to mention that this is a good answer :)   FWIW, if I can, I will always go with logical indexing!

Answer (score 2):

seems there's no need to use regex:

```
str = '<foo_boo>'
str([strfind(str,'<'),strfind(str,'>')]) = []
```

Comment: Good use on `strfind`.  IMHO I think `regexprep` is more readable though... just a personal preference!